# How can Black free his game?

Tags: pawn-structure, middlegame, french-defense

- What are Black's long term plans in below pawn structure?
- How can Black free his game?

The position arose from the Rubinstein variation of the French defense:

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "r2rb1k1/1p2bppp/1q2pn2/p3B3/P2N4/2PB4/1P2QPPP/R2R2K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, my idea is this:

- pawn structure should remain as is except pawn should be probably on
  g6 preventing king side attacks and giving space to move bishop
  Be7-f6-g7
- move knight to better position Nf6-d7-c5 and focusing attack on weak
  pawn a4 with help of white squared bishop
- move black squared bishop to a1-h8 diagonal which will make pressure
  on pawn c3 if white b pawn is moving to protect a pawn

It doesn't look as good endgame for black since he has minority on queen side which can quickly turn into passing pawn therefore I believe black should keep pieces.

Comment: I have upvoted, because I like the piece setup, but this seems hard to achieve. Concrete lines could be helpful... I will try to implement your suggestions and report my results...

Comment: I forgot to say... Welcome to Chess SE!

Comment: Thanks, I am some semi-pro strong FM but mostly doing programming stuff...
Anyway, I'd start with Nd7 pinning bishop, I think that white will most probably have to move it and then Nc5 followed with Bf6 and g6

Comment: *I am some semi-pro strong FM but mostly doing programming stuff...* I am programmer too, with similar strength :) I have tried your plan, it seems it works. Give me more time to test it because this wil be the part of my opening repertoire ( you know how tough it is to play an opening well from 2300 ELO onwards, especially this type of position ). We shall hear soon ( if you need help with chess diagrams just leave me a comment and I will help ).

Comment: I was looking for `1...Nd7 2.Bf4 e5 3.Bxe5 Nxe5 4.Qxe5 Bf6 ( or Bc5 )` line for past few days, trying to make it work but it fails in the end. I am now looking for ways to implement your suggestion in the most efficient way. If you need help with adding chess diagrams/variations in your answer please see [this thread](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch/280#280). I apologize for taking this long, but I need to examine this thoroughly...

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look on those diagrams, I was really wondering how to add them. :)

Comment: I have officially accepted your solution, as I believe there is no other way for Black to play this position. After playing this against engine, I was able to hold the game. It was tough, but still your general plan worked. Thank you. Best regards until next time.